# Launching webview class from status bar notification

Tags: android

When I click on my status bar notification it loads my webview, but it reloads it everytime. is there a way to load the saved state? Thanks here is what I have:

```
    @Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Now playing...";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Music Promotion";
    CharSequence contentText = "Now Playing...";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, mainmenu.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);



    mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);

}
```

Comment: Hello please explain your question/ your requirements or put your code here so understanding will be easy.

Comment: My app is a webview that launches the mediaplayer when an mp3 link is clicked and it also creates a status bar notification when this happens. When you click the status bar notification it launches my mainmenu.class which is the webview. The webview loads from scratch when this happens and I do not want that to happen. I want it to open and not do anything (remaind on the webpage they were on)

Comment: i edited the question with more code. i think its firing the onCreate method when i click the status bar notification and i don't want it to do that. i just want it to switch to the view or open it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following:

```
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

This is what the docs say about `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`:

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's
>   history stack if it is already running.

Comment: What I did was set the launch mode in the manifest to singleInstance

Comment: I suppose that is an easier approach, unless there's actually a time where you need to reload the web view instead of using the history. Just depends on the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

i changed the launch mode in the android manifest to singleInstance and that seemed to have done the trick